# Xcode - Add multiple views in NSGridView cell

Tags: swift, xcode, nsgridview

I added a `NSImageView` inside a `NSGridView` Cell and now want to add a `NSLabel` on top of it.
When dragging the `NSLabel` on the `NSImageView` the `NSImageView` disappears and is replaces by the `NSLabel`.
Is there a way in interface builder to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding multiple subviews on top of `NSGridViewCell`, how about adding a `NSView` first as the sole `NSGridViewCell`'s subview, and then adding whatever you want on top of that view?